# Auto send notification (Android - Java)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

How can I create notifications at a specific time of day *(For example, at 12 AM)*.  I tried to find it in the documentation but didn't find anything that could help me *(probably looked bad)*.  If you need more details, we can discuss it.

Comment: You're looking for `AlarmManager`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AlarmManager

This example its works for me.

In Manifests

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Alarm"></receiver>
```

Link:
[AlartmManager notifications Example](https://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/)